# Java Cucumber: get the current environment

Tags: java, junit, cucumber, cucumber-junit

I want to run the same cucumber scenario with different URLs:

for example, if I run this command, it should use Prod URL:

```
 maven test -someOptions Prod
```

this one for Dev URL:

```
 maven test -someOptions Dev
```

and then use this parameter to set up my environment

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setUp(){
   String env = getEnvOption();
   if(env.equals("Prod")){
      url = "http://prod"
   }else{
      url = "http://dev"
   }
}
```

I want to know how can I pass the environment parameter to my cucumber scenario and how to get the current environment.

Comment: Use this `maven test -DsomeOptions Dev`. Access in java using `System.getProperty("someOptions")`